# Flask request.form.to_dict()

Tags: python, flask

I'm facing a problem. I developed an API in Flask.
I use **python-requests** to send **POST** requests (with dictionaries) to my API.
Below, an example of how I sent requests.

```py
import requests

data=dict()
data['a'] = "foo"
data['b'] = "bar"
data['ninja'] = {"Name": "John doe"}

r = requests.post("https://my_own_url.io/", data=data, headers={"content-type" : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, verify=False)
```

---

On the back-end of my flask application, I can received the request :

```py
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def home():
    content = request.form.to_dict()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is my problem, I send a python dictionary :

> {'a' : "foo", 'b' : "bar", 'ninja':{'Name': "John Doe"}}

But I can only recover :

> {'a' : "foo", 'b' : "bar", 'ninja':'Name'}
> Here **ninja** haven't the right value.

Do you know the right way to aim this ? :)

Comment: If you are using a POST request, use `request.args` instead.

Comment: You can't send complex nested objects with `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` Consider using JSON or some similar format instead

Comment: Well, it seems complicated. But how can I manage a json-like entry (dict, multidict ...) if I need to send a file (located in request.files) ?

> 'application/json' doesn't allow file and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' doesn't allow complex nested objects.
So you can't send both obkect in a single request ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the data on the server side (Flask app) as json, so you can use [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.get_json) or [`request.json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.json):

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def home():
    content = request.get_json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Send it on the client side as:

```
import requests

data = dict()
data['a'] = "foo"
data['b'] = "bar"
data['ninja'] = { "Name": "John doe" }

r = requests.post("https://my_own_url.io/", json=data, verify=False)
```